# Resetting latitude and longitude does not create map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

[image]

I'm trying to build a vue google map component using google maps and the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps. I have installed the plugin using npm , and I've got in working when my googleMap.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>

        <v-container row fill-height justify-center style="max-width: 1200px"  >


      <v-flex>




<span style="display:block">
  <GmapMap

  :center="{lat:10, lng:10}" 
  :zoom="7"
  map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
>
  <!-- <GmapMarker
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    :clickable="true"
    :draggable="true"
    @click="center=m.position"
  /> -->
</GmapMap>
</span>
          </v-flex>
  </v-container>
  </div>

</template>


<script>

var latitute = 1030.08674842
var longitude = -97.29304982

export default {
  // name:'myMap'
  latitute,
  longitude

}

</script>


<style>


</style>
```

Where it shows a map of Nigeria. I have a map I would like to display with this component:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@30.086753,-97.2952385,17z
```

I took the lat and long above and substituted in in so it looks like the screenshot, with the controls but no map:

```
  :center="{lat:1030.08674842, lng:-97.29304982}"
```

I've checked my console at :

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/maps-backend.googleapis.com/metrics
```

all the requests today have 200 status codes

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check latitude value you are using

{lat:1030.08674842, lng:-97.29304982}

I think you are using wrong Latitude value.